# How to align list in <section> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am fairly new to web development and there is still some issues I can resolve by myself.

I have this code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="column">

<div id="colunmA">
<section>
<h1 class="en">Column A</h1>
<ul>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list A1</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list A2</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list A3</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list A4</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list A5</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>

<div id="colunmB">
<section>
<h1 class="en">Column B</h1>
<ul>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list B1</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list B2</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list B3</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list B4</a></li>
<li class="en"><a href="#">list B5</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
     ul , li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#column{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 200%;
  }

  #colunmA{

    }

 #colunmB{

    }

 #colunmC{

        }
```

I left rules #colunmA , #colunmB and #colunmC in CSS empty because I don't know what to put in here.

I would like to align all elements that belong to each column together. Also, elements in column C do not align horizontally and vertically with the others columns. I would like to achieve a similar result:

[image]

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gdiop/s9w2ku8q/24/

Comment: you have unclosed div and wrong id selector.

Comment: you need something like this https://jsfiddle.net/s9w2ku8q/26/

Comment: Leo the lion , one problem solved ! But how about aligning header and elements ? I would like "column A"  to be vertically aligned with its contents. How to proceed ?

Comment: add `padding:0;` to `ul, li`. you can also use a small value for it for better appearance: like as  `padding: 4px;`

Comment: Very nice ! It solved my problem. Thanks ^_^

Comment: @GabrielD. please upvote useful posts ;D. i have post an answer with simpler css. please look and feedback.

Comment: So I have implemented the code ito y project. But I have no clue how o center it ....

Answer (score 0):

You are placing your elements in little bit wrong way.
No need to make seperate rules for Column A,B,C. Always try to make general rules which can by applied to n-number of things.

Here is yout updated JSfiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s9w2ku8q/27/)

I added float and margin property to #column.

CODE:

```
<div id="column">
  <div id="colunmA">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column A</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A4</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A5</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A6</a></li>

      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="column">
  <div id="colunmA">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column B</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list b1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list b2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list b3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list c5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="column">
  <div id="colunmA">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column C</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list c1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list c2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list c3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 200%;

  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#colunmA {}

#colunmB {}

#colunmC {}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove from #column selector the align-items: center;
then u can add to each of your columns selector margin:0 20px;
for make a space between columns.

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 200%;
}

#colunmA {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

#colunmB {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

#colunmC {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="column">

  <div id="colunmA">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column A</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A4</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="colunmB">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column B</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B4</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="colunm C">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column C</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: But he want to left-align the header and list items in each column!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on comments provided by me. note that the css is very simple and same class is applied to all columns A, B, C. i use class instead of id for simpler code:

```css
ul , li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2px;
}

.columns {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.colunmItem { /* same class for columnA,B,C */
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 300%; /* control line spacing for list items */
  margin:0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">

  <div class="colunmItem">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column A</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A4</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list A5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="colunmB" class="colunmItem">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column B</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B3</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B4</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list B5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="colunmC" class="colunmItem">
    <section>
      <h1 class="en">Column C</h1>
      <ul>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C1</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C2</a></li>
        <li class="en"><a href="#">list C3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: looks like this code works on my project. But how to center it in the middle of the div  and make some space between the lines ?

Comment: i have updated the code snippet, i removed the floats and use inline-block with some text-align and vertical-align css. please take a look

Comment: very great ! Thanks very much

Comment: to specify the right ans worked for you, click the **tick** mark at left side of the answer, near that upward / downward arrows which are for up-voting or down-voting it. this increase ranking of good coders as they help others